# How can expand and a particular div by clicking a +/- icon in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I want to have + icon to expand and - collapse a particular div. I have Array of objrcts so i'll iterate using *ngFor="let data of dataArray"

I have the example to achieve this using accordion. But i want to open all the div when i click + and close the particulat div when I click "-" icon of the particular div. But accordion will open only one at a time

I want to have something like below

**-** **data[0].name**

```
  {{data[0].categoryName}} , {{data[0].groupName}}
```

**-** **data[1].name**

```
  {{data[1].categoryName}} , {{data[1].groupName}}
```

**+** **data[2].name**
**+** **data[3].name**
**-** **data[4].name**

```
  {{data[4].categoryName}} , {{data[4].groupName}}
```

I want to open it in Top-Down and also need a scroll bar when the content is big

Comment: You don't say whether you want top down, or left to right... If you open more than one at once, do you want page to scroll if content is too big etc... You'd need to clarify, and from what you are describing that's more like a treelist. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index

Comment: Please look at my updated question

Comment: So is that demo link close to what you want? or this... http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/index

Comment: Yes. Almost the same. But I'll have only one layer associated with the top layer

Comment: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/angular-2-samples/#/demo/countries

Comment: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/lazy-loaded-treeview-in-angular-2.0

Comment: Exactly as http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/animation    (Furniture,  Decor, storage)

Comment: Th one top layer will probably be something you can work out with some markup..

Comment: Then my advice is to study the html/css/jquery etc and see how to map that to Angular.. They'll have done hard work.. Also Google on it with Angular 2... That's sort of what I was doing.. Seems Treeview rather than Accordion will give you a better result. Good luck...

Comment: Also if you can't find something close to what you want in Angular, make an attempt, revise your question and post the code you've got. If you create it in Plunker too, you can share code via a link and you'll get far more help then...

Comment: One final thought.. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree - check out the library - that's Angular2

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply and feedback

Answer (score 1):

The most basic form of what you want can be created this way.

You can always add more css and styles to make it look the way you want.

ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div class="div" *ngFor="let data of dataArray; let i = index" (click)="iconChange(i)" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
        <div>
          <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-plus': flagArray[i] == false, 'fa-minus': flagArray[i] == true}" aria-hidden="true" style="float: left"></i>
          {{data.name}}
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="flagArray[i] == true" class="div2">
            {{data.categoryName}} - {{data.groupName}} 
          </div>
        </div>
        <button (click)="showAll()">Expand All</button>
        <button (click)="hideAll()">Collapse All</button>
    </div>
  `,
  stylesUrl:['./style.css']
})
export class App {

  flagArray = [];

  dataArray = [];

  selectedIndex: number;

  constructor() {

    this.selectedIndex = -1;

    this.dataArray = [
    {name: '1', categoryName: 'A1', groupName: 'G1'},
    {name: '2', categoryName: 'A2', groupName: 'g2'},
    {name: '3', categoryName: 'A3', groupName: 'G3'},
    {name: '4', categoryName: 'A4', groupName: 'G4'}
  ]

    for(let  i=0; i<this.dataArray.length; i++){
      this.flagArray.push(false);
    }
  }

  iconChange(i: number){
    this.flagArray[i] = !this.flagArray[i];
  }

  showAll(){
    for(let  i=0; i<this.dataArray.length; i++){
      this.flagArray[i] = true;
    }
  }

  hideAll(){
    for(let  i=0; i<this.dataArray.length; i++){
      this.flagArray[i] = false;
    }
  }
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/m4dTsI3EmHuijPKPNfDz?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

1. [Angular Boostrap collapse](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/api) component
2. [*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) to make your own collapsible html or bind a [hidden] if you want to pre-load and keep the DOM while not displayed. You can then use [angular animation modules](https://angular.io/guide/animations) to add an animation.

Answer (score 0):

While implementing this yourself would probably be interesting, if you're looking to save on work, there's a<s>n app</s> **component library** for that!

https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component

 or 
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-tree